# React native BackHandler action is save in next page

Tags: react-native, event-handling

I used BackHandler to config back button in android, this is my code:

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.backAction);
  }

  backAction = () => {
    this.props.resetPage("Home");
    return true;
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.backAction);
  }
```

But on the next page, if i don't config Backhandler, I press back, it was  `this.props.resetPage("Home")`, besides how to configure it, is there a way for me to destroy it? Thank you

Comment: You need to check if you are on that page, where you configure BackHandler action.

Comment: I use ```NavigationActions.navigate``` i think the next page is on that page, i configure BackHandler action in prev page

Comment: When you navigate from `Screen1` to `Screen2`, `Screen1` isn't destroyed, they are stacked and that's why you need to check on which screen you are now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you give me some way to check on which screen now?

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation`?

Comment: Yes, i am using ```react-navigation```

Comment: How is your screen called, where you set listener?

Comment: I am using ```createStackNavigator``` from ```react-navigation``` and import screen in this, then i call ```NavigationActions.navigate``` for navigate to my screen i need

Comment: Yes but every screen has a unique name and I wonder what is your screen's name.

Comment: My first screen's name is ```OtherScreen```, and second screen is ```Configuration``` .